# too many nginx waiting connections

Tags: nginx, tcp, connection

My nginx status below：

```
Active connections: 1156598
server accepts handled requests
     429477742 429477742 2435052040 
Reading: 353 Writing: 45136 Waiting: 1111109
```

As we can see, there are 1111109 waiting connections.

But with ss -s I only get 24453 tcp connections:

```
Total: 17618 (kernel 0)
TCP:   24453 (estab 17007, closed 6489, orphaned 622, synrecv 0, timewait 6466/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         0         -         -        
RAW       0         0         0        
UDP       2         2         0        
TCP       17964     17961     3        
INET      17966     17963     3        
FRAG      0         0         0
```

The value of Waiting connections is much higher than TCP connections, is it normal?

Comment: What do 24W, 110W stand for?

Comment: do you have any segfaults? dmesg|grep nginx|grep segfault|wc -l

Answer (score 8):

Those are keepalive connections. They are usually not a problem. But if you want lower the number reduce **keepalive_timeout**.

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/203409